# Mishnayot at house of a mourner

Tags: mishna, mourning-aveilus

There is a tradition to learn mishnayot at a mourner's house, where the mishnayot chosen start with the letters from the deceased person's name. (Lists of mishnayot corresponding to each letter can be found in the back of, e.g., the Artscroll bereaevment siddur.)

Is anyone aware of good (online) references containing short divrei Torah for mishnayot that are appropriate for a mourner's house?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend being in touch with *Chevrah Lomdei Mishnah*, [The Society for Mishna Study](https://www.chevrahlomdeimishnah.org/mishnah-study-offered-to-mourners/), you can email their coordination team here: info@societyformishnahstudy.org

Their main job is to study on your behalf, but I'm sure they would be the ones to ask about how to find a good set of *divrei Torah* to accompany the study relevant to mourners and in fact there are many links on the page above to divrei Torah relevant to mourners.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first answer. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Thank you. I’d still be happy to see other recommendations that people may have.